# crawl a non-structured page with scrapy

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler, bigdata

I'm currently struggling while implementing a Spider for a Web Application, because my pages are not well structured at all. There're fields on the page, but sometimes they don't appear, and it's difficult to distinguish those because they only use class, not id as identifier. Is there a method to optimize the way we get the data in pages?

Below, an example of one page to crawl :

```
    <div class = 'view-activity-field-wrapper even' style = 'display:none' >
       <div class="view-activity-label">Status Notes            <span><img src="/images/helpIcon.png" alt="" width="8" height="10" align="absmiddle" data-tooltip="stickyStatusNotes" /></span>
      </div>
                                    <div class="view-activity-field"></div>     
    </div>
    <div style = 'clear:both'></div>
    <div class = 'view-activity-field-wrapper odd' style = 'display:none'  >
       <div class="view-activity-label">Relevant Question            <span><img src="/images/helpIcon.png" alt="" width="8" height="10" align="absmiddle" data-tooltip="stickyRelevantQuestion" /></span>
      </div>
                                    <div class="view-activity-field"></div>     
    </div>
    <div style = 'clear:both'></div>

    <!-- KEEP VALUE PROVIDED HERE -->
    <div class = 'view-activity-field-wrapper odd' style = 'display:none' >
       <div class="view-activity-label">Value Provided           <span><img src="/images/helpIcon.png" alt="" width="8" height="10" align="absmiddle" data-tooltip="viewvalueprovided" /></span>
       </div>
                                    <div class="view-activity-field"></div>     
    </div>
    <div style = 'clear:both'></div>
```

Comment: What data are you interested in in the page?

Comment: It depends on pages, some are modules, for which I'd like to get a report on the module (Module name, Source data, Author etc...) and some are data request, for which I'd like to get (Activity Name, Source data, and other relevant information). But it's complicated to have the same field result on two similar pages, which is annoying.

Comment: Welcome to web scraping. You'll need to find some invariant feature of the page and select data relatively to that "anchor." For example, it could be the title of some section, or the Nth element of some list etc. Then you can use relative XPaths, using following siblings or descendants. It's hard to help you without 2 different example input where you show us what you need in both with the same solution. Also, it would help if you showed what you tried already.

Comment: I think using xpath could be the most realistic solution, I'll try to add as much details as possible soon.